# YiiBooster - middle mouse button click links disabled?

Tags: php, twitter-bootstrap, yii

I have an Yii app and I use YiiBooster. I noticed that I can't open links using middle mouse button. That is really bad as I can't open link in new tab for example.

Is it by default? How can I change it?

Comment: Yii boster demos middle button works, my yii project with yiibooster works too, so i guess its not because of that. Maybe you have some global click event or something?

Comment: Do you use it with YiiBoilerplate or just the booster?

Comment: This is weird. It works in every browser (Opear, IE...) but not in Firefox.

Comment: Maybe some FF extension?

Answer (score 2):

i had the same problem.. confirm that is a issue for version 1.0.6 of booster only with  firefox browser.
i resolved after a downgrade to version 1.0.5!

i know that this isn't a solution but is better that nothing ;)

best regards!!!

Salsero